# How to add out of stock products on other page in woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

i'm searching for this query, please help me out i want to make a category for out of stock items and i want to add items in it when products get out of stock.
On a separate page i want to show the out of stock products. Maybe assign a new category of out of stock

SELECT * FROM `wp_postmeta` WHERE meta_key = "_stock_status" && meta_value="outofstock";

this is the query i've run in database but i have to show these products on a page

Thanks.

Comment: WooCommerce have a native shortcode to display all sale products on a page: https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-shortcodes/#section-15 - You can use this: [sale_products per_page="12"]

Comment: Thanks David, But actually i want to show only products which are out of stock on a separate page.

Comment: sorry, I totally misread out of stock for sale...

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
<?php
global $product;
$availability = $product->get_availability();
if ($availability['availability'] == 'Out of stock') {
            // 
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try pasting this code at the bottom of your function.php file, right before the closing tag;

```
   /**
 * @snippet       Display All Products Out of Stock via a Shortcode - WooCommerce
 * @how-to        Get CustomizeWoo.com FREE
 * @author        Rodolfo Melogli
 * @compatible    Woo 3.6.1
 * @donate $9     https://businessbloomer.com/bloomer-armada/
 */

add_shortcode( 'out_of_stock_products', 'bbloomer_out_of_stock_products_shortcode' );

function bbloomer_out_of_stock_products_shortcode() {

   $args = array(
      'post_type' => 'product',
      'posts_per_page' => -1,
      'post_status' => 'publish',
      'meta_query' => array(
         array(
            'key' => '_stock',
            'value' => 1,
            'compare' => '<'
         )
      ),
      'fields' => 'ids',
   );

   $product_ids = get_posts( $args ); 
   $product_ids = implode( ",", $product_ids );

   return do_shortcode("[products ids='$product_ids']");

}
```

Then paste shortcode [out_of_stock_products] on the page you'd like to display the sold out products. Make sure you enable visibility of out of stock items in woocommerce inventory settings for this to work.

Got this off https://businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-display-stock-products-shortcode/